# Multi tenant authentication using Duende

Tags: c#, .net, identityserver4, duende-identity-server

I want to set up a centralized identity server using Duende Identity Server which will authenticate multiple tenants (with separate databases). I have searched the internet and tried samples from git hub. None of them really helped. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to do that:

- Integrate [external providers](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/ui/login/external/) via OIDC or via [Dynamic Providers](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/ui/login/dynamicproviders/)
- Use [data stores](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/data/) and implement your Identity Provider

The first approach allows you to use many identity providers(Microsoft, Google, or your own, etc.). The latter will enable you to build your identity provider but you need to build a store and logic yourself. IDS only gives you interfaces to inject implementation and some basic flows.

Nonetheless, both approaches need to store data.